# Sending data from datagridview to crystal report using VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, crystal-reports

Hy guys
I have one problem.

I have 3 important column, they are: Nama,Hasil, and Satuan.
Nama and Satuan column is getting from database
But not for Hasil column
Value for Hasil column is entered manual,
so How can I get that value in crystal repotrt?
Would you like to see and help me?
Thank you very much

```
Dim MyRrpt As New CR_TestOrder2
Dim dsOrder As New DataSet

Dim listkode As New List(Of String)
Dim row As DataGridViewRowCollection
row = dgv_hasillab.Rows

dt_order = New DataTable
dt_order.Clear()
dt_order.Columns.Add("Pemeriksaan")
dt_order.Columns.Add("Hasil")
dt_order.Columns.Add("Nilairujukan")
dt_order.Columns.Add("Satuan")

For j As Integer = 0 To dgv_hasillab.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim cek As Boolean = CBool(row(j).Cells(6).Value)
    If cek = True Then
        dt_order.Rows.Add(row(j).Cells(1).Value, row(j).Cells(2).Value, row(j).Cells(3).Value, row(j).Cells(4).Value)
    End If
Next

dsOrder.Tables.Add(dt_order)
'aman -cara I 
Frm_TestOrder.crv_testorder.SelectionFormula = "{tabelpasien.nama}='" + txt_namaOrder.Text + "'"
MyRrpt.SetDataSource(dt_order)

Frm_TestOrder.crv_testorder.ReportSource = MyRrpt
Frm_TestOrder.crv_testorder.Refresh()
Frm_TestOrder.Show()
```

Comment: where are you getting stuck ..can you elaborate question please

Comment: I can't transfer daa from datagridview to crystal report @SreenathGanga

Comment: do you have data at dt_order when you put breakpoint at dsOrder.Tables.Add(dt_order)

Comment: yes, I have. @SreenathGanga

Comment: Ok now .I think I got your problem ..you have Hasil  column which is not in database. So when you designed  report its not added in 
crystalreport..now you want to send it manually..But since not in report it will not display...can you confirm ?

Comment: yes, Sir! you got the point @SreenathGanga

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182711/discussion-between-sreenath-ganga-and-winda-sari-elisabeth-siburian).

Comment: hi sir, would you like to help me? @SreenathGanga

Comment: Seriously I like to help you that s why i tried to continue on chat..because the information provided is not enough..

Comment: i've replied your message sir in Chat. @SreenathGanga